# WSO2 Custom Message Mediator Sample Starting Point

Tags: wso2-esb

I've got a streaming UDP application that generates a stream of messages in a legacy format. These messages are generated in an un-solicited fashion (that is, it is not request/response).

I'd like to build a custom message mediator to take these messages into an enterprise network.

Can someone please point me to one or more samples in the WSO2 ESB portfolio that are a good starting point for building a custom mediator?

Any other samples, or examples, to serve as a starting point for a WSO2 ESB novice that needs to develop his first custom mediator would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can refer these links.

(Creating a project by userself and compile a custom mediator jar)
http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/Writing+a+WSO2+ESB+Mediator

(Using WSO2 Developer studio)
http://achala11.blogspot.com/2012/12/how-to-write-custom-mediator-wso2-esb.html